# Custom Dnsmasq DNS Arista/Untangle Firewall, NextDNS

Tags: networking, dns

Wondering if it's possible to use multiple DNS profiles at NextDNS through custom Dnsmasq settings.

This is the default code provided but I've been trying to edit with no luck in have different vlans/interfaces point to their own profile. Please help in letting me know what needs to be added or removed. Regardless what I've tried this code seem to be global and affects all interfaces.

> Use the following in dnsmasq.conf:
>
> ```
> no-resolv
> bogus-priv
> strict-order
> server=2a07:a8c1::
> server=45.90.30.0
> server=2a07:a8c0::
> server=45.90.28.0
> add-cpe-id=<profile>
> ```

Basically what I'm asking is how do you route DNS request based on source interface or subnet.

I've tried adding tags, interfaces etc.